# Wordpress meta_query relationship

Tags: wordpress, relationship, meta-query

The following query does not work correctly for me,
Where is my mistake in this?

```
$incidents = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => array('incident'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-5 month", strtotime('now')))
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'forma4_checked_date',
                'meta_value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime("12 hours", strtotime('now'))),
                'compare' => '>',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'forma4_checked_date',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'forma4',
                'meta_value' => 'received',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'forma4',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        )

    )
]);
```

i need to run one script for **$incidents->posts**
After this update meta forma4 and forma4_checked_date

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "not working correctly" to you? What's the expected behavior vs what you're seeing with your code?

Comment: this code should return forma4 != received
but return same posts

Answer (score 0):

oops,

meta_key instead of key
meta_value instead of value